# Find complement set of a given set A and a universal set U in Haskell

Tags: haskell, set

I have tried to write a function (complement), which given a set A and a universal set U, returns a complement of A with respect to U, wrapped in the Just type constructor. I have to double check if the set A is not a subset of U, in that case, I should return Nothing.

Basically, I found few resources that explain how to check if a set (in our case A), is a subset of U. 
http://www.multiwingspan.co.uk/haskell.php?page=subsets
Basically, it is enough to use the "subset" function (that return a boolean), to see if A is a subset of B.

I found an as well different website that explains how to create the complement set without implement recursively functions, using:

```
import Data.Set(Set)
import qualified Data.Set  as Set
```

The only problem is that I CANNOT import any external modules to solve this problem.

The signature of the function is:

```
complement :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Maybe [a]
```

I expect the following output:

```
complement [1,2,3] [1..5] = Just [4,5]
complement [1,2,3] [2..5] = Nothing
```

Can anyone help me to deal with it?

Comment: What's your first attempt? You've not shown any effort so far, please do so.

Comment: I really don't think this is going to be particularly pleasant to write in terms of lists if you're not allowed to convert to sets along the way. And it will certainly be very inefficient.

Comment: So, what did you try so far?

Comment: Try to recurse on the first list argument.

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to solve your problem for you - I believe the solution should be your own work. However, I will provide a list of functions which could assist you, and which you don't have to import:

- `filter f list`: returns all elements of `list` where `f element` returns `True`. For instance, `filter (\x -> (x /= 0)) [0,1,0,2,3]` gives `[1,2,3]`. This is useful with the `not` function, which inverts a `Bool`; for instance, `filter (\x -> not (x > 2)) [1,2,3,4,5]` gives `[1,2]`.
- `all f list`: returns `True` if `f` gives `True` for all elements of `list`. For example, `all (\x -> (x /= 0)) [1,2,3]` gives `True`; however, `all (\x -> (x /= 0)) [1,0,2,3]` gives `False`.
- `` x `elem` list `` (which is really just syntax sugar for `elem x list`) returns true if `x` is an element of `list`. For example, `` 1 `elem` [1,2,3] `` gives `True`, but `` 0 `elem` [1,2,3] `` gives `False`.

Again, I won't directly give you the solution to this problem. But I can guarantee you that if you put the above functions together in the right way - together with the `Just` and `Nothing` constructors - you can make your `complement` function.

Comment: I think this is the same solution I came up with. Using the `MonadComprehensions` extension can also eliminate the need for explicitly using `Just` or `Nothing`